# Using <= and >= in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I would like to use `<=` and `>=` when comparing values in `<xsl:if test="">`. How to do that?

Update:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Average classsize per user and module</h1>
        <table border="1">

            <tr>
                <th>User Email</th>
                <th>Module Code</th>
                <th>Average Value</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//classsize" />
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="average">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=". &lt; 1">
            <td style="background-color: red;"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="1 &lt;= . &lt; 2">
            <td style="background-color: blue;"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="2 &lt;= . &lt; 3">
            <td style="background-color: yellow;"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <td style="background-color: white;"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//classsize">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="email" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="modulecode" /></td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="average" />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

```
average < 1 - in red
1 <= average < 2 - in blue
2 <= average < 3 - in yellow
average >= 3 - white
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for examples how you can write comparisons without having at all to escape `<`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In addidtion to @Oded's correct answer**:

.1. **There is never any need to escape the `>` operator in XSLT. Just write: `>`**

.2. **One can avoid escaping the `<` operator**.

Instead of:

```
  x &lt; y
```

you can write:

```
not(x >= y)
```

Instead of:

```
1 &lt;= . and . &lt; 2
```

you can write:

```
2 > . and not(1 > .)
```

.3. **In XPath 1.0 the `<` and `>` operators are not defined on strings (only on numbers).**

**Finally**, this is actually an XPath 1.0 question.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Also instead of `x &lt; y` you could write it as `y > x`.

Answer (score 4):

You can escape the `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively.

See the example for `xsl:if` on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_if.asp).

---

Update:

After seeing you condition, I am not surprised it doesn't work.

Instead of:

```
1 &lt;= . &lt; 2
```

Try:

```
1 &lt;= . and . &lt; 2
```

You can't chain the `<` and `>` like that in XSLT.

Comment: <xsl:when test="1 &lt;= . &lt; 2">
            <td style="background-color: blue;"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
        </xsl:when>

Comment: @Moshin - then you have another problem, please post your code.

Comment: Instead of `1 &lt;= . &lt; 2` try `1 &lt; . and . &lt; 2`. If you still have problems then post a sample XML input document.

Comment: @Oded: +1 Good answer. As a minor: you **can** "chain" comparison operators, but the result for a comparison is a boolean value that will be implicitly cast to a number (0 or 1) for the next comparison (unless it's a equality comparison)